Exporting multiple imported components for efficiency/readability?
I'm working with a project that makes many imports from a particular library, but importing from the dist rather than being more generic.
ie.
import {Header} from '@some-lib/.../.../dist/Header';
import {Footer} from '@some-lib/.../.../dist/Footer';
import {Column} from '@some-lib/.../.../dist/Column';
import {Button} from '@some-lib/.../.../dist/Button';
import {Radio} from '@some-lib/.../.../dist/Radio';

rather than
import {Header, Footer, Column, Button, Radio} from '@some-lib';

While I understand that this is done for greater efficiency and more specificity in what we import into each component, it really clogs up the file with a million imports at the top and doesn't look all that attractive.
Would it be possible to perhaps have a separate file in which we can import all of the lib's components from their respective dist locations and re-export them such that we can achieve a single line import, but with the benefits of performance of the multi-line?
For example:
// libImportExport.js
import {Header} from '@some-lib/.../.../dist/Header';
import {Footer} from '@some-lib/.../.../dist/Footer';
import {Column} from '@some-lib/.../.../dist/Column';
import {Button} from '@some-lib/.../.../dist/Button';
import {Radio} from '@some-lib/.../.../dist/Radio';

export {Header, Footer, Column, Button, Radio};

// MyComponent.jsx
import {Header, Footer, Column, Button, Radio} from './libImportExport';

...

Or is this a pointless effort to make?

It's common to re-export function from a so called "mod" file sometimes "mod.ts/js" sometimes "index.ts/js". In such a file you simple write export * from "./dist/Header and list all the exports. Is this what you're looking for? AFAIK without code gen you can't dynamically re-export everything since imports need to be statically analyzable. Tree shaking should work regardless.

That sounds about right. I don't know why I did the import/export and not just export *. Brain fart XD

Great, I'll add an answer in case someone sees this Q&A and has the same problem

You can re-export your components from an index file.
@some-lib/index.js
export * from "./dist/Header";
export * from "./dist/Footer";
...

And then import it from the dependent:
import { Header, Footer } from "@some-lib";


Didn't you mean export * from...? ;-)

good catch, fixed
